# scanf() не возвращает EOF

Tags: c, строки, scanf

Я написала программу, которая просит на вход строку, и если было введена не строка, то функция должна вернуть EOF, но чтобы не поступало на вход, функция scanf не возвращает EOF

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[10];
    short int result;

    printf("Enter any str:");
    result = scanf("%s", str);

    if (result == EOF)
    {
        printf("EOF!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
        printf("Good!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Расскажите, как вы планируете ввести **не строку** - это что такое? Кстати, `%s` вводит не строку, а одно слово, но пока это непринципиально...

Comment: Допустим я даю на вход слово, а если будет введено число, то возратится EOF

Comment: `%s` читает символы до пробела. Не важно, цифры или буквы.

Comment: А что, 234 - это не строка из символов 2, 3 и 4?...

Comment: Точно, вспомнила, но мне надо как-то сделать проверку вводимых типов данных, вот в этом и проблема

Comment: Что значит "сделать проверку вводимых типов данных"? Какой спецификатор Вы указываете в `scanf`, то она и пытается прочитать. Для нее все равно все данные приходят в виде текста, а в зависимости от спецификатора, она преобразует их в нужный тип. Вы можете узнать удалось ли ей прочитать что-то. `scanf` возвращает количество успешно прочитанных элементов.